# How can I Pull base image of JDK and TOMCAT for building an image for my application

Tags: docker

My Application needs JDK and Tomcat as dependencies. How can I pull both during the build process?

Below is my Dockerfile...

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

MAINTAINER admin

COPY /App-UI.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY /App-Backend.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

I want to have Tomcat and jdk in my image/container . Please help

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything; if the `tomcat:8.0` base image isn't present on your local system, `docker build` will pull it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pull jdk container into tomcat. Because the Tomcat runs on java.

You can find the `java -version` by adding `RUN java -version` command to your Dockerfile.

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

RUN java -version


Step 2/2 : RUN java -version
 ---> Running in 0ebfd70e0e47
java version "1.7.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.14) (7u181-2.6.14-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.181-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Thanks much hari. It helped